# R regex extract text not immediately following pattern

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a data frame with a column containing semi-structured text.  I'm looking for certain pieces of information but they have a pattern I'm not sure how to exploit.

```
head(events5)
     flight_history_id         date_time_recorded              event
862          280604281 2012-11-13 17:55:58.673-08 Arrival Estimation
5514         280316415 2012-11-12 17:25:08.814-08    Time Adjustment
5527         280315758 2012-11-12 16:10:06.968-08    Time Adjustment
5539         280316495 2012-11-12 15:38:10.099-08    Time Adjustment
5545         280303866 2012-11-13 06:51:45.831-08    Time Adjustment
5558         280303866 2012-11-12 05:50:23.547-08    Time Adjustment
                                                                               data_updated
862                                                     EGA- Based on Distance and Airspeed
5514                        EGD- New=11/13/12 20:20, DGATE- New=A1, EGA- New=11/13/12 21:00
5527         EGD- New=11/13/12 19:05, DGATE- New=A7, EGA- New=11/13/12 20:50, AGATE- New=C5
5539                        EGD- New=11/13/12 06:35, DGATE- New=A1, EGA- New=11/13/12 07:15
5545 AGD- Old=11/13/12 07:40 New=11/13/12 07:38, EGA- Old=11/13/12 10:25 New=11/13/12 10:18
5558         EGD- New=11/13/12 07:45, DGATE- New=11, EGA- New=11/13/12 10:25, AGATE- New=A1
```

here's the dput:

```
structure(list(flight_history_id = c(280604281L, 280316415L, 
280315758L, 280316495L, 280303866L, 280303866L, 280271465L, 280271465L, 
280271465L, 280271465L), date_time_recorded = structure(c(10L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("2012-11-12 05:50:23.547-08", 
"2012-11-12 15:38:10.099-08", "2012-11-12 16:10:06.968-08", "2012-11-12 17:25:08.814-08", 
"2012-11-12 17:58:14.268-08", "2012-11-13 05:16:41.01-08", "2012-11-13 06:51:45.831-08", 
"2012-11-13 07:38:19.593-08", "2012-11-13 07:54:22.588-08", "2012-11-13 17:55:58.673-08"
), class = "factor"), event = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Arrival Estimation", "Time Adjustment"
), class = "factor"), data_updated = structure(c(3L, 8L, 7L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 6L), .Label = c("AGD- New=11/13/12 10:22, EGA- Old=11/13/12 11:20 New=11/13/12 11:09", 
"AGD- Old=11/13/12 07:40 New=11/13/12 07:38, EGA- Old=11/13/12 10:25 New=11/13/12 10:18", 
"EGA- Based on Distance and Airspeed", "EGD- New=11/13/12 06:35, DGATE- New=A1, EGA- New=11/13/12 07:15", 
"EGD- New=11/13/12 07:45, DGATE- New=11, EGA- New=11/13/12 10:25, AGATE- New=A1", 
"EGD- New=11/13/12 08:55, EGA- New=11/13/12 09:45, AGATE- New=A1", 
"EGD- New=11/13/12 19:05, DGATE- New=A7, EGA- New=11/13/12 20:50, AGATE- New=C5", 
"EGD- New=11/13/12 20:20, DGATE- New=A1, EGA- New=11/13/12 21:00", 
"EGD- Old=11/13/12 08:55 New=11/13/12 10:05, EGA- Old=11/13/12 09:45 New=11/13/12 10:55", 
"EGD- Old=11/13/12 10:05 New=11/13/12 10:30, EGA- Old=11/13/12 10:55 New=11/13/12 11:20"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("flight_history_id", "date_time_recorded", 
"event", "data_updated"), row.names = c(862L, 5514L, 5527L, 5539L, 
5545L, 5558L, 5564L, 5566L, 5570L, 5572L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to extract the field `'New='` portion of the parts starting with `'EGA'` from the column `'data_updated'`. The problem is sometimes there is an 'Old=' field in between the two.  I looked at using stringr::str_split and turning the column into a list, but still have the same issue.  I assume this is a regex/gsub issue, but don't know exactly how to implement.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I'd like the end product to be a vector / column with the EGA/New value.  So something like this:

```
NA
11/13/12 21:00
11/13/12 20:50
11/13/12 07:15
11/13/12 10:18
11/13/12 10:25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start-to-end solution:

```
##formats of the date-times
date.format <- "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}"
##puts this together into a regex
regex.string <- paste0("EGA- (?:Old=",date.format," )?New=(",date.format,")")

##if pattern matches, get the part of "new" we are looking for
##otherwise NA
ifelse(grepl(regex.string,events5$data_updated),
  gsub(paste0("^.*",regex.string,".*$"),"\\1",events5$data_updated),
  NA_character_)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about that?

```
EGA-\s*(?:Old=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}\s*)?New=(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2})
```

Comment: how would I incorporate that in a gsub statement?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that will compared to @Pharaoh's regex work with an unlimited amount of text after the `EGA`-tag

```
/EGA-(?:(?!New=|").)+(New=[:\d\/ ]+)/g
```

If the `"` in the negative lookahead is too general, you can just change it to say `EGD`.

Demo+explanation: 
http://regex101.com/r/qY4uA0

Remove the flag and delimiters if they are not needed.

Comment: Aren't you skipping through whole entries, like `EGA- Based on Distance and Airspeed 5514 EGD- New=11/13/12 20:20` (whitespaces and linebreaks trimmed) so you get the wrong `New=`? // Yes you are, just checked your demo

Comment: That is absolutely correct @Pharaoh. I had missed that. Let me get to it. Edit: done

Comment: @Lindrian: how would I incorporate that in a gsub statement?

Comment: @screechOwl: Do you want to match or replace here? `gsub(pattern, replacement) → new_str`

Comment: @Lindrian: match, sorry I meant grep and wrote gsub instead.

Comment: @Lindrian: I'd like to output the EGA/New value to a vector or column of a data frame.

Comment: @screechOwl: Alright. I am not the best with grep, `man grep` is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar in concept to @BlueMagister's but without as much nesting:

```
gsub(".*EGA-.*New=([0-9/]{8} [0-9:]{5}).*|.*EGA.*", "\\1", events5$data_updated)
# [1] ""               "11/13/12 21:00" "11/13/12 20:50" "11/13/12 07:15"
# [5] "11/13/12 10:18" "11/13/12 10:25" "11/13/12 11:09" "11/13/12 11:20"
# [9] "11/13/12 10:55" "11/13/12 09:45"
```

Basically, the first part of the `gsub` says to look for "EGA-", which does not necessarily come at the start of the string, and start capturing when you encounter "New=". The capture pattern `([0-9/]{8} [0-9:]{5})` says you first expect a string with digits and slashes 8 characters long, followed by a space, followed by a string with digits and colons 5 characters long. Then the `|` character is used to say also look for EGA with anything before or after it.

To add the new information to your `data.frame` you can use something like:

```
within(events5, {
  EGA.New <- gsub(".*EGA-.*New=([0-9/]{8} [0-9:]{5}).*|.*EGA-.*", 
                  "\\1", events5$data_updated)
})
```